# Trying to change the background color of a box - CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking after a portal on a low-code platform. I am trying to update the background-color for a box on our portal, however am really struggling to update this.

I have copied the selector and also included a screenshot from the console.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate that.

[image: console]

div.ideas-list--cntr.ng-scope > div > div.panel.panel-default.ideas-list--panel > div > div.panel-body.ideas-list--content > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > div.idea-details--cntr > div.ideas-categories--cntr > a

Thanks
Mike

I have tried updating the background color as follows and was expecting a white background for the box:

```
.ideas-list--panel .ideas-categories--cntr a {
  background-color: white;
}
```

However, I am still seeing #33466C background color.
[image: box]

Comment: What does the web inspector say? Is the new rule with the `background-color: white` crossed out? If so, you hit the correct selector, but the specificity is too low, maybe because that rule is set _before_ the rule you're attempting to override, try setting it after, or increase specificity with something like `!important`. However, if the rule doesn't appear in the inspector at all, you made a mistake somewhere, either in the selector or where you included that CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much silvenon - adding  !important  solved the problem. If you can post that as an answer I can mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override the backgorund color the new rule should have bigger specificity than the rule you're overriding, you can achieve this either by:

- adding your overriding rule *after* the original CSS in HTML,
- increasing the specificity of the selector with techniques like repeating a class, for example `.ideas-list--panel.ideas-list--panel .ideas-categories--cntr a`,
- or ending the declaration with `!important`

These techniques are ordered starting from the ideal practice, so pick the one that is easiest for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is another part of the selector which you erased with red color in your screenshot –  this makes it more specific than your selector, so your rule won't apply due to a lower css specifity.

Use the *complete*  selector from your screenshot, then it should work.

Comment: Hi Johannes, This is a GUID for the widget. I erased it out for security purposes. It isn't required to be added in the CSS